# Get a value from an ASPX page to an SPA website mobile through out jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Referring to my previous post here [Add <li> dynamically reading from a folder photoswipe purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594727/add-li-dynamically-reading-from-a-folder-photoswipe-purpose/20613998?noredirect=1#comment30854713_20613998)

I'll explain a bit the environment on which I am working, I have got an SPA Website Mobile on a apache server I need to get dinamically the names of the file .jpg present on the same server to build the 
`<li>` tags for PhotoSwipe that works fine. So if you read the previous post the answer was to use php to do this job but since I don't know at all that server language I prefer to use aspx page but of course it will be on another 
web server. So I would know the most easy way to do that. Do I need to use and aspx or asmx I just need to build the html containing all `<li>` tags and append to my `<ul>`.

I on the (SPA) client side I wrote this.

```
$("#page").live("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    alert("Start Json ");

 $.getJSON('http://mysite:port/mypage.aspx', function (json) {

 function(data){
        $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
            $("ul#PhotoList").append('<li><a href="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + ' rel="external"><img src="' + item.images.low_resolution.url + '" alt="' + item.caption.text + '" width="200" /></a></li>');
        }); 
});
});
```

on my aspx instead:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

in page load I build my html put in  string variable and than

```
Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim sHTMLResponse As String = "http://Mysite.linktomyimage.jpg"
jsonString = js.Serialize(sHTMLResponse)
Response.Write(jsonString)
```

it is a simple aspx without any special configuration. Do I need to set something in particular or it is enough the code above?

The error message is "XMLHttprequest" cannot load  `'http://mysite:port/mypage.aspx'` No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. Origin null is therefore not allowed access.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that the correct path? ASPX is most certainly not the top level domain. You need a slash after your domain name.

Comment: Sorry you are right the path is like this I've made a typing mistake //PublicIP:Portn/page.aspx

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using temporary my local IIS, with port forwarding to use it as server.